# Extending Protobuf with my own methods

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How should I add methods a Protobuf message?

Suppose I have in my .proto file:

```
package proto;
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;    
}
```

and I want to add a method, say, string `concatenateNameEmail()` to the message.

What I do right now is I create my own C++ class like this:

```
class Person : public proto::Person
{
public:
  Person( proto::Person const & person_ )
  : proto::Person(person_)
  {}

  string concateNateNameEmail()
  {
   ...
  }
};
```

So the downside is I need to call proto::Person copy constructor. Is there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: I don't think the first block of code containing "package" and "message" is valid C++ syntax.. The reason "package" is syntax highlighted is probably because it is a keyword in some language, but I don't think it is a keyword in C++.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear. The first code block is a proto message definition. Let me clear up the post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Google Protobufs are specifically not intended to be extended. Here's a paragraph from the documentation (in the middle of this: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html):

> Protocol Buffers and O-O Design
>   Protocol buffer classes are basically
>   dumb data holders (like structs in
>   C++); they don't make good first class
>   citizens in an object model. If you
>   want to add richer behaviour to a
>   generated class, the best way to do
>   this is to wrap the generated protocol
>   buffer class in an
>   application-specific class. ... **You
>   should never add behaviour to the
>   generated classes by inheriting from
>   them.** This will break internal
>   mechanisms and is not good
>   object-oriented practice anyway.

I can see how such advice would seem annoying if you only wanted that one method, but in general it's pretty good advice. If you really have no other functionality to warrant creating an application-specific "Person" class, there is nothing wrong with just defining a top-level function:

```
string concatenateNameEmail(const proto::Person &person) { ... }
```

Comment: I think an example of good practice still needs to be added.